# Is there a conjectured uniform Lindelof hypothesis for Hurwitz zeta functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

Consider $\zeta(s, a) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+a)^{-s}$ (alternatively, consider its functional equation Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}e(a n) n^{-s}$).  What is the expected growth-rate of $\zeta(1/2 + i T, a)$ for $a$ away from 0?

When $a=\frac{m}{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$ these are finite linear combinations of Dirichlet L-functions mod $n$.  Hence, assuming GRH, $\zeta(1/2 + i T, m/n) \ll_n T^{\epsilon}$.

If the Lindelof hypothesis is a phenomenon of Euler products, arithmetic, zero-free regions, then one could expect that the implied constant grows large with $n$, and that there is no such bound for irrational $a$.

If the Lindelof hypothesis is an analytic phenomenon, one could expect that $\zeta(1/2 + i T, a)\ll T^{\epsilon}$ uniformly for $a$ away from $0$.

Are there any computations or conjectures pointing one way or the other?  Or other ways that we do or not have nice control of the behaviour with respect to $a$.

Comment: One comment on Lindelof being an analytic phenomenom.  As far as I know there is "nothing" that is known or conjectured to fail Lindelof.  To make this precise, Dirichlet series $\sum a_n n^{-s}$ with $a_n\ll n^\epsilon$ that extend to an entire function with polynomial growth on vertical lines (this class includes all L functions) all appear to satisfy the Lindelof hypothesis, and have sub-polynomial growth to the right of $1/2$.  The bound on the coefficients is meant to exclude counterexamples like $\zeta(2s-1)$.

Comment: Indeed, linear combinations of functions satisfying Lindelof will also satisfy Lindelof, but rarely have Euler products. Some can be arranged to retain nice functional equations, but this seems un-necessary.

Comment: Right. There provably cannot be non-trivial linear combinations between things with either Euler products, or satisfying a Riemann hypothesis.  On the other hand, the exponential twists above form a (continuous) basis for everything with a degree 1 growth rate, so Lindelöf for them gives Lindelöf for all other small Dirichlet series. I don’t know of an analogous continuous family of higher degree functions.